# PHP - fetch data using class

Tags: class

```
<div id="gallery">

<a href="url/stock_img2/36536/1.jpg" class="gallary-tmb"><img src="url/stock_img2/36536/1.jpg" alt="TIIDA LATIO 15B" /></a>

<a href="url/stock_img2/36536/2.jpg" class="gallary-tmb"><img src="url/stock_img2/36536/2.jpg" alt="TIIDA LATIO 15B" /></a>

</div><div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Hey guys , The above is the partial source code of the page i need to fetch data from .

What i need is only the url of the 2 values for the class "gallary-tmb" e.g :

$thumb1 = "url/stock_img2/36536/1.jpg";

$thumb2 = "url/stock_img2/36536/2.jpg";

I have no idea how to get the data - I'm thinking using the class or preg_match  , whichever is simpler

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. Don't just tell us whatyou need/want and expect us to do your job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code f.eks echoes all the values of 'src' nodes from "img" Elements.

```
<?php
 $str = <<<EOD
 <div id="gallery">

 <a href="url/stock_img2/36536/1.jpg" class="gallary-tmb"><img src="url/stock_img2/36536/1.jpg" alt="TIIDA LATIO 15B" /></a>

 <a href="url/stock_img2/36536/2.jpg" class="gallary-tmb"><img src="url/stock_img2/36536/2.jpg" alt="TIIDA LATIO 15B" /></a>

 </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
 EOD;

 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML($str);

 $p = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");

   foreach ($p as $node) {
     if ($node->hasAttributes()) {
       foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
         if ($attr->nodeName == "src") {
           echo $attr->nodeValue;
         }
       }
     }
   }
?>
```

instead to deal with regex and preg_match it is a more general approach to deal with the dom.

Comment: Hi , It seems to work but giving too broad results (all images )

Comment: Is there any way to make it work for the specific class : class="gallary-tmb">

Comment: use this code: $p = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");

foreach ($p as $node) {
        if ($node->hasAttributes()) {
                if($node->getAttribute('class') == "gallary-tmb") {
                        foreach ($node->attributes as $attr) {
                                if ($attr->nodeName == "href") {
                                        echo $attr->nodeValue;
                                        echo "\n";
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}

Comment: Thanks - works great - I also used array_push to put each element inside an array